# How to add a className to an EasyUI react component

Tags: reactjs, jquery-easyui

I would simply like to add some styling to the `DateBox` `react` component defined as in the code below

Let's say I'd like to change the width of the panel, something like:

```
<DateBox className="myClassName"></DateBox>
```

but this  did not work. My actual component is:

```
import React from "react";
import { DateBox } from 'rc-easyui';
import "./style.css"   

class DatePick extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DateBox>
        </DateBox>
      </div>
    );
  }
}    
export default DatePick;
```

How can I specify the DateBox component styling className (not the div in which is contained), assuming `myClassName` is defined in `style.css`?

Thank you for any suggestions!

> EDIT: let me be more specific using an example. Suppose I would like
>   to change the background color of the above EasyUI react component:
>   how to achieve that in the code I'm using?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a `className` to a component, it looks at it as a prop. So, you'll need to apply the `className` to an actual html markup tag within the DateBox component.

Or, you could apply the style to the parent div that the component resides in, which may or may not suit your needs.

According to the [docs](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/#), you could also apply a `style` tag (prop), like so:

```
<DateBox style='some class or inline style'>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, it's not what I'm looking for. I need to change the style of the DateBox react EasyUI component (eg. dimension, background color, border, etc..), not to the parent div (wich may contains other stuff)